# Java- import data in a html table in JSP to EXCEL and to pdf

Tags: java, javascript, excel, html-table

i am working on a jsp project and i have few jsp where i am showing the searched data in HTML. when i made the same in window in swings, Jtable made it all very easy to build function and IO but i can't figure out how to convert the html table data in jsp to excel and pdf on the click of a button.

can anyone help me in this case anything from javascript to core IO code will do as i can't find anything useful on internet anywhere if u have a useful link will do too.

the basic structure of html table is used with href in some columns

Comment: To export Data to Excel you can use Apache POI or JExcel. To export data in PDF form there is the iTextPDF project.